# How to translate "quiver"? (mathematics)

Tags: traducción, matemáticas

In mathematics a [quiver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiver_%28mathematics%29) is  a multidigraph. It is a directed graph that allows multiple arrows and loops. The non-mathematical Wikipedia article on the *quiver*, corresponds to the Spanish article on *carcaj* o *aljaba*.

*Is there a standard Spanish translation for the mathematical term?*

Comment: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un _Quiver_ y un multigrafo dirigido?

Comment: Dado que tu pregunta requiere de un alto conocimiento de tal argot, creo que debes considerar su migración a [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a mathematician, but, according to what I read in the link you provided:

> a quiver is a directed graph where loops and multiple arrows between two vertices are allowed, i.e. a **multidigraph**

So, *multidigraph* is [***multigrafo***](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigrafo) in Spanish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1, Gracias Dante, sólo que un _quiver_ parece ser algo más específico. Más bien pregunto no por una posible traducción, sino por una estándar, que ya esté en uso en el argot matemático.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Hoy mismo se ha creado una propuesta en Area51.StackExchange llamado 'Mathematics in Spanish', podrías intentar preguntar allí: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50091/mathematics-in-spanish

Answer (score 1):

In English, a *quiver* the container for the collection of arrows.  So the vocabulary must come from archery.

Here's a list of Spanish archery terms http://www.lograrco.es/pdf/Diccionario.pdf they suggest **carcaj**

The spanish experts on quivers are [Daniel Labardini Fragoso](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/labardin/) and [Oscar Chacaltana](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.2930).  I wonder what word they use.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17949100/carcaj.gif

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17949100/quiver.gif

Comment: nice catch! you got +1

Comment: It can be also **aljaba**, being a synonym AFAICS